# How to modify a recursive branch and bound tree node traversal to avoid stack overflow?

Tags: swift, recursion

I created the following Swift 3 program to solve knapsack problem using the depth-first branch and bound. Unfortunately, it's recursive. It works fine for up to 20 items. But for a higher number of items (30 or higher), it will cause the stack overflow. ( ~5400 level deep).

How to change it to a non-recursive version?

```
public enum BBState {
case created
case active
case death
}

public enum Direction {
case left
case right
}

public class BBTreeNode {
    public var artifact: Artifact
    public var nodeState: BBState
    public var level: Int
    public var path = [Direction]()
    public var weightSoFar: Int = 0
    public var optimumTotalValue: Int = 0
    public var estimatedOptTotalValue: Double = 0
    public weak  var parentNode: BBTreeNode?
    public var leftNode: BBTreeNode?
    public var rightNode: BBTreeNode?
    static var currentCompletedOptimumValues: Int = 0
    static var currentCompletedEstimatedOptimumValues: Double = 0
    static var currentOptimumPath = [Direction]()

// Initialization
public convenience init(artifact: Artifact) {
    self.init(artifact: artifact, level: 0, path: [], parent: nil, left: nil, right: nil)
}

public init(artifact: Artifact, level: Int, path: [Direction], parent: BBTreeNode?, left: BBTreeNode?, right: BBTreeNode?) {
    self.artifact = artifact
    self.nodeState = .created
    self.level = level
    self.path = path
    self.parentNode = parent
    self.leftNode = left
    self.rightNode = right
}


// BBTree
private func createRootAndInitiateBB(artifacts: [Artifact]) {
    // return the optimum value from Depth-First branch and bound
    let maxLevel = artifacts.count - 1
    print("Max Level: \(maxLevel)")
    // create dummy Root to start
    let root = BBTreeNode(artifact: Artifact(value: 0, weight: 0))
    root.estimatedOptTotalValue = Knapsack.calculateEstimatedOptimumValue(availableArtifacts: artifacts)
    root.nodeState = .active
    root.weightSoFar = Knapsack.capacity
    // loop here for each artifact# - selected(left) / not(right) but going recursive to left until
    // we have death node, then backtrack

    func depthFirstTraversal(bbNode: BBTreeNode?, level: Int) {
        guard let bbNode = bbNode  // not nil
            else { return }

        guard level <= maxLevel
            else { return }

        print("Currently on path: \(bbNode.path)")

        // switch to active is last state was created, else ignore
        bbNode.nodeState =  bbNode.nodeState == .created ?  .active : bbNode.nodeState

        // stop traverse down and traceback if calculated optimumValue < currentCompletedOptimumValue,
        // or current weightSoFar is 0 or less than 0
        // move up to parent
        if bbNode.estimatedOptTotalValue < BBTreeNode.currentCompletedEstimatedOptimumValues ||
            bbNode.weightSoFar < 0 {
            print("Case for estimatedOptTotalValue: \(bbNode.estimatedOptTotalValue) < currentCompletedEstimatedOptimumValues: \(BBTreeNode.currentCompletedEstimatedOptimumValues)")
            print("Or weight: \(bbNode.weightSoFar) < 0" )
            bbNode.nodeState = .death
            // remove references to children
            bbNode.leftNode = nil
            bbNode.rightNode = nil
            depthFirstTraversal(bbNode: bbNode.parentNode, level: bbNode.level - 1)
        } else if (bbNode.leftNode?.nodeState == .death &&
                bbNode.rightNode?.nodeState == .death) || level ==  maxLevel  {

            print("Case for no more path available. Need to backtrack. ")
            print("Current level: \(level)")
            // stop, record and traceback if at maxLevel or when both children are death
            if level == maxLevel && bbNode.estimatedOptTotalValue > BBTreeNode.currentCompletedEstimatedOptimumValues {
                BBTreeNode.currentCompletedEstimatedOptimumValues = bbNode.estimatedOptTotalValue
                BBTreeNode.currentCompletedOptimumValues = bbNode.optimumTotalValue
                BBTreeNode.currentOptimumPath = bbNode.path
                print("blah...")
                print("Candidate for optimum: \(bbNode.path)")
                print("Completed optimum path: \(BBTreeNode.currentCompletedOptimumValues)")
                print("Estimated optimum value: \(BBTreeNode.currentCompletedEstimatedOptimumValues)")
            }
            bbNode.nodeState = .death
            // remove references to children
            bbNode.leftNode = nil
            bbNode.rightNode = nil
            let _ = path.popLast()
            depthFirstTraversal(bbNode: bbNode.parentNode, level: bbNode.level - 1)
        } else if bbNode.leftNode == nil {
            // create left child
            print("create left child node")
            let childLeftNode = createBBNode(leftChild: true, parent: bbNode, path: bbNode.path + [.left])
            bbNode.leftNode = childLeftNode
            depthFirstTraversal(bbNode: childLeftNode, level: childLeftNode.level)
        } else if bbNode.rightNode == nil {
            // create right child
            print("create right child node")
            let childRightNode = createBBNode(leftChild: false, parent: bbNode, path: bbNode.path + [.right])
            bbNode.rightNode = childRightNode
            depthFirstTraversal(bbNode: childRightNode, level: childRightNode.level)
        }

    }

    func createBBNode(leftChild: Bool, parent: BBTreeNode, path: [Direction]) -> BBTreeNode {
        let level = parent.level + 1
        let artifact = artifacts[level]
        let newBBNode = BBTreeNode(artifact: artifact, level: level, path: path, parent: parent, left: nil, right: nil )
        if leftChild {
            newBBNode.optimumTotalValue =  parent.optimumTotalValue + artifact.value
            newBBNode.estimatedOptTotalValue = parent.estimatedOptTotalValue
            newBBNode.weightSoFar = parent.weightSoFar - artifact.weight
        } else {
            // right direction, we don't pick this item
            // Artifact is a struct,  artifacts is array of Artifact, so we don't need to write deep copy 
            var artifactsWithItemsRemoved = artifacts

            print("Current artifacts before any removal: \(artifactsWithItemsRemoved)")
            print("for path \(newBBNode.path) we are going to remove artifacts...")
            // first remove the dummy artifact 
            artifactsWithItemsRemoved.remove(at: 0)
            // now the real artifacts
            var indexOfItemForRemoval = [Int]()
            for (index,direction) in path.enumerated() {
                if direction == .right {
                    indexOfItemForRemoval.append(index)
                }
            }
            // actual removal, need to reverse the array index to avoid out of range index
            for idx in indexOfItemForRemoval.reversed() {
                artifactsWithItemsRemoved.remove(at: idx)
            }

            print("Artifacts with items removed: \(artifactsWithItemsRemoved)")

            newBBNode.optimumTotalValue = parent.optimumTotalValue
            newBBNode.estimatedOptTotalValue = Knapsack.calculateEstimatedOptimumValue(availableArtifacts: artifactsWithItemsRemoved)
            print("New estimatedOptValue for \(newBBNode.path) is \(newBBNode.estimatedOptTotalValue)")
            // no weight deduction if we don't pick
            newBBNode.weightSoFar = parent.weightSoFar
        }
        return newBBNode
    }

    depthFirstTraversal(bbNode: root, level: 0)
}

public func findOptimumValueAndPath(artifacts: [Artifact]) -> (Int,[Direction], Double) {
    createRootAndInitiateBB(artifacts: artifacts)
    return (BBTreeNode.currentCompletedOptimumValues, BBTreeNode.currentOptimumPath, BBTreeNode.currentCompletedEstimatedOptimumValues)
}

}
```

==== Update ===

I manage to limit the depth of recursion to certain limit like 4000, once the counter reach limit, I returned to caller with currentNode information. Then call the 'depthFirstTraversal' again with currentNode but with fresh new stack.

Here's how I do it:

1. Move createRootAndInitiateBB and findOptimumValueAndPath to the caller.
2. Update depthFirstTraversal to have function signature like this:

   static func depthFirstTraversal(bbNode: BBTreeNode, level: Int, recursiveCount: Int, complete completeFlag: inout Bool, currentProcessedNode: inout BBTreeNode)
3. Some other refactoring work to keep the counter count and some bug fixed. (e.g. parentNode should not be weak, else after return to caller, the parent of currentNode become nil and we lose capability to backtrack to higher node).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that might help you or anybody else stumbles on your question:

https://github.com/evansjohnson/DynamicProgrammingWithSwift/blob/master/ProblemSet8Playground.playground/Contents.swift